# Calling API from Powershell throws UnAuthorized error

Tags: powershell, rest, c#-3.0

```
$tenantId = tId;
$clientId = [System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[5];
$clientSecret = [System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[6];
$audience = [System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[2] + "/";
$domainUrl = [System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[7];

$httpClient = [System.Net.WebClient.HttpClient]::new();

$httpClient.BaseAddress = [System.Uri]::new($domainUrl);
$httpRequestBody = "{ \"client_id\": \"" + clientId + "\", \"client_secret\": \"" + clientSecret + "\" , \"audience\": \"" + audience + "\"," +  " \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\", \"TenantId\": \"" + tenantId + "\"}";

$jsonContent = [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new($httpRequestBody, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8, "application/json");
$relativeUrl = $"oauth/token";
$httpResponse = $httpClient.PostAsync($relativeUrl, $jsonContent).Result;
if ($httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
 $jsonString = $httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 $obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString.ToString());
 $accessToken = obj["access_token"].ToString();
 return $accessToken;
}
```

I have generated a bearer token with the above script. With this as header I want to call a Rest API endpoint from my powershell script. But I get unauthorized error. Am I passing it properly?

```
$apiEndpoint = "https://localhost:xxxx/api/ElasticSearch/deleteIndex?indexName=123"
$headers = @{
"Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
 "Content-Type" = "application/json"
 }
try {
  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiEndpoint -Method DELETE -Headers $headers
 Write-Output "API Response: $($response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
 } catch {
 Write-Output "Error calling the API: $($_.Exception.Message)"
 }
```

The below is the error I get :
Error calling the API: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: You would get another error is the request was wrong.  Error 401 means you not have the permission to access the route.  The authentication is good the credentials is the issue.